# How to keep multiple handles from overlapping in jQuery UI slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I want to have a jQuery UI slider with two handles that can be set with their values independent of each other.

I also want them to be styled so that one handle is "on top" of the slider and the other handle is below.

The problem is that when the two handles share the same value, jQuery UI thinks that one of the handles is still "on top" so one of the handles needs to be moved before the other one can be adjusted. If the top handle is set to a value, then the bottom handle is moved to the same value, the top handle can't be moved until the bottom handle is moved off first. The scenario is hard to describe so there's a fiddle link below.

Is there any way to specify to jQuery UI that the handle I'm clicking is the one I want to be actively moved?

JS Fiddle link here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rqpndLsL/

How my slider is set up:

```
$('.slider').slider({
    min: 0,
  max: 400,
  step: 50,
  values: [200, 200],
  range: false,
})
```

Comment: The actual problem is `min` & `max` values, the reason why the bottom handler is not able to move is because logically **Max cannot be less than the Min value**

Comment: The min and max values are to set ranges for the slider itself - how high or low either handle can go. I removed those values and the problem persists.

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqpndLsL/3/)

Comment: Still doesn't work. If you drag the top handle on top of the bottom handle, then try to move the bottom handle, it moves the top one instead. It happens when the two handles have the same value. It's difficult to make the two handles the same value in your example because the step is set to 1, but if you change it to something like 500, it's easier to see the issue.

Comment: Hmm ok ... added a new tag now - "jquery-ui-slider". Hopefully reaching the right people with expert opinions.

Comment: I managed to find a solution that worked for me. I posted it below and will mark it as an answer in 24 hours - take a look if you're curious. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but this solution ended up working for me. I'm answering here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Looking into the jQuery API, it looks like the active handle is calculated based on some kind of distance, when what I wanted was just the handle that is being clicked on.

I overrode the jQuery UI _mouseCapture event and customized it to be click-sensitive. It also needed some hard set CSS class detection to determine which handle is the active one.

By doing something like this, I was able to avoid modifying any library files and only changed a small amount of the original function.

```
// Create the slider.
var slider = $('.slider').slider({//OPTIONS HERE});

// Get the slider and replace the _mouseCapture function with a custom one.
slider.data('ui-slider')._mouseCapture = function(event) {
  var position, normValue, distance, closestHandle, index, allowed, offset, mouseOverHandle,
        that = this,
        o = this.options;

  if ( o.disabled ) {
    return false;
  }

  this.elementSize = {
    width: this.element.outerWidth(),
    height: this.element.outerHeight()
  };
  this.elementOffset = this.element.offset();

  // Get the element that the click was triggered on and set that to closestHandle. There was a bunch of distance calculation here previously - that has been removed.
  currentHandle = $(event.toElement);
  closestHandle = currentHandle;
  // 'custom-handle-1' is a custom class I give to the left slider handle
  // I know that my sliders will only have 2 values (so index will either be 0 or 1 always).
  if (closestHandle.hasClass('custom-handle-1')) {
    index = 0;
  }
  else {
    index = 1;
  }

  allowed = this._start( event, index );
  if ( allowed === false ) {
    return false;
  }
  this._mouseSliding = true;

  this._handleIndex = index;

  this._addClass( closestHandle, null, "ui-state-active" );
  closestHandle.trigger( "focus" );

  offset = closestHandle.offset();
  mouseOverHandle = !$( event.target ).parents().addBack().is( ".ui-slider-handle" );
  this._clickOffset = mouseOverHandle ? { left: 0, top: 0 } : {
    left: event.pageX - offset.left - ( closestHandle.width() / 2 ),
    top: event.pageY - offset.top -
      ( closestHandle.height() / 2 ) -
      ( parseInt( closestHandle.css( "borderTopWidth" ), 10 ) || 0 ) -
      ( parseInt( closestHandle.css( "borderBottomWidth" ), 10 ) || 0 ) +
      ( parseInt( closestHandle.css( "marginTop" ), 10 ) || 0 )
  };

  if ( !this.handles.hasClass( "ui-state-hover" ) ) {
    this._slide( event, index, normValue );
  }
  this._animateOff = true;
  return true;
};
```

The downside is that this may not be compatible with future versions of jQuery UI, but that's a future problem (Currently this is 1.12.1).

Comment: Hmm nice .... It looks more of a JQuery solution than UI Slider, which could be bad like you mentioned. But to be fair I guess for this issue you had to take the unconventional way since the library did not provide it. Atleast you found a good solution. Cheers